# Stopping thread Immediately

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to stop a running thread immediately. Here is my code:

Class A :

```
public class A() {
    public void methodA() {
        For (int n=0;n<100;n++) {
        //Do something recursive
        }
        //Another for-loop here

        //A resursive method here

        //Another for-loop here

        finishingMethod();        
    }    
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B() {
    public void runEverything() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    A a = new A();
                    a.methodA();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
       Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
       thread.start();
    }
```

My problem is that i need to be able to stop the thread in Class B even before the thread is finished. I've tried interrupt() method, but that doesn't stop my thread. I've also heard about using shared variable as a signal to stop my thread, but I think with long recursive and for-loop in my process, shared-variable will not be effective.

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Thread.interrupt` will not stop your thread (unless it is in the sleep, in which case the `InterruptedException` will be thrown). Interrupting basically sends a message to the thread indicating it has been interrupted but it doesn't cause a thread to stop immediately.

When you have long looping operations, using a flag to check if the thread has been cancelled is a standard approach. Your `methodA` can be modified to add that flag, so something like:

```
// this is a new instance variable in `A`
private volatile boolean cancelled = false;

// this is part of your methodA
for (int n=0;n<100;n++) {
  if ( cancelled ) {
    return; // or handle this however you want
  }    
}

// each of your other loops should work the same way
```

Then a cancel method can be added to set that flag

```
public void cancel() {
  cancelled = true;   
}
```

Then if someone calls `runEverything` on `B`, `B` can then just call `cancel` on `A` (you will have to extract the `A` variable so `B`  has a reference to it even after `runEverything` is called.

Comment: +1 For volatile. Would be good to add explanation as to why it matters.

Comment: The volatile keyword is needed since the thread doing the cancelling will not be the same thread that is being cancelled. Marking it is volatile ensures that the thread checking the flag will see the up to date value.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Im sorry for my ignorance. But, is it correct that if i have lots of loops and recursive methods then the only way to achieve this is by adding flag checks everywhere ?

Comment: To make it cancellable, that is probably the easiest way to do this. There is no way to safely just kill a thread, so you need to allow it to exit cleanly (you could check if Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() if you interrupt it, but interrupted is often used incorrectly, so that's not always reliable).

Comment: @frcb: Well you don't have to check the flag *everywhere*. Usually, checking at one or two key points will be sufficient.

Comment: The thread interrupt mechanism is reliable, but sloppy code often catches and ignores InterruptedException. That might be what Jeff Storey means by it not being reliable. OTOH if the target thread is blocked in wait() or sleep() or join(), interrupting it will work better since there is no opportunity to check a flag while blocked.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. There is sloppy usage of it which often leads to thread interrupts not being correctly propagated. And yes, the interrupt is the way to break out when you're in a method that is blocked as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should persevere with using `Thread.interrupt()`.  But what you need to do to make it work is to change the `methodA` code to do something like this:

```
public void methodA() throws InterruptedException {
    for (int n=0; n < 100; n++) {
        if (Thread.interrupted) {
             throw new InterruptedException();
        }
        //Do something recursive
    }
    // and so on.        
}
```

This is equivalent declaring and using your own "kill switch" variable, except that:

- many synchronization APIs, and some I/O APIs pay attention to the `interrupted` state, and
- a well-behaved 3rd-party library will pay attention to the `interrupted` state.

Now it is true that a lot of code out there *mishandles* `InterruptedException`; e.g. by squashing it.  (The correct way to deal with an `InterruptedException` is to either to allow it to propagate, or call `Thread.interrupt()` to set the flag again.)  However, the flip side is that that same code would not be aware of your kill switch.  So you've got a problem either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status of the run flag as part of the looping or recursion. If there's a kill signal (i.e. run flag is set false), just return (after whatever cleanup you need to do).

Answer (score 0):

There are some other possible approaches:

1) Don't stop it - signal it to stop with the Interrupted flag, set its priority to lowest possible and 'orphan' the thread and any data objects it is working on.  If you need the operation that is performed by this thread again, make another one.

2) Null out, corrupt, rename, close or otherwise destroy the data it is working on to force the thread to segfault/AV or except in some other way.  The thread can catch the throw and check the Interrupted flag.

No guarantees, sold as seen...

Answer (score 0):

From main thread letsvsay someTask() is called and t1.interrput is being called..

```
t1.interrupt();

    }

    private static Runnable someTask(){
        return ()->{



            while(running){
                try {
                    if(Thread.interrupted()){
                        throw new InterruptedException(  );
                    }
               // System.out.println(i + " the current thread is "+Thread.currentThread().getName());


                  //  Thread.sleep( 2000 );
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    System.out.println(" the thread is interrputed "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

o/P:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at com.barcap.test.Threading.interrupt.ThreadT2Interrupt.lambda$someTask$0(ThreadT2Interrupt.java:32)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 the thread is interrputed Thread-0
```

Only `t1.interuuption` will not be enough .this need check the status of Thread.interrupted()  in child thread.