# Is there some way to stop thread immediately?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there is some way in Java to stop thread immediately. I don't want to check its interrupted status, I need to stop it immediately. That's because in thread's run method there are many calculations and to achieve what I want using interrupted I would have to inject status check everywhere. So is there some way to interrupt thread immediately? Maybe stop() method? I know it's is said it shouldn't be used because of deadlocks but if it could solve my problem (even if it would cause another ;) ) I could use it. So? ***P.S.*** I know there were other, similar questions but everywhere people give similar questions to interrupted() which doesn't suit me.

Comment: How do you know when to stop it?

Comment: http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911118/stopping-thread-immediately

Comment: `Thread#stop` is your only choice so why don't you use it and hope for the best.

Comment: stop() is deprecated for several reasons really - you should try your utterly best to avoid it. What's so bad with status checks?

Comment: @Pescis I wrote what's wrong. Wrong is that I'm doing many calculations which goes sequentially and I would need to put interrupted status checkings in every possible place.

Comment: A status check isn't very costly, really. Also, why is it so important that you need to stop it **directly**? If you show some code we could give you some specific guidelines.

Comment: Im writing simple editor and code coloring is made in thread (to avoid log in many lines). While key is pressed I need to immediately stop coloring thread and start new one.

Answer (score 2):

[The question/answer that @Alya'aGamal points to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911118/stopping-thread-immediately) is the right one.

If your app's design assumes that forcibly stopping a thread, or a process, or a program (like using `kill -9` or stopping it via the Task Manager on Windows) is an okay thing to do, then you really need to justify that, because it sounds like a bad design choice. If you used someone else's app and the only way to close it on demand was to forcibly stop it, wouldn't you think that was a rather major flaw?

If you have long-running loops or algorithms and it's important to be able to stop them at an arbitrary point then you **MUST** put some kind of regular status or signal check in place in order to do this properly.

Always design your apps in a way such that there is a nice, friendly, graceful way for them to exit from all situations other than things outside your control (e.g. another app starts saturating the CPU, a hard disk dies, a RAM chip gets fried, a meteor hits the Earth, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's not a good idea to just kill a thread, which is why the `stop()` method has been deprecated.  It's just too easy to introduce deadlocks this way.  There are other reasons why stopping a thread externally is bad, but I won't get into them here.

Status checks really are the only other way to go, but I can understand why you'd want to avoid them.  Checks add overhead and make the code cumbersome if your `run()` method has many lines of code...  but there's simply no other thread-safe way to stop a thread.

That said - there are four components of deadlock: mutual exclusion, hold and wait, non-pre-emption, and circular wait.  If you can guarantee that any one of these conditions will never be met inside your `run()` method, then you will never encounter a deadlock by calling `stop()`.