# How I can interrupt a running thread immediately while performing SVN checkout?

Tags: java, multithreading, svn

I have a swing application in which a child thread performs SVN checkout. When user close the application if the SVN checkout is in progress by the child thread I am interrupting the child thread from main thread and I am able to catch the InterruptedException in Child thread. In catch block I am deleting the partially checked out contents from SVN which is a mandatory task to perform.  But it takes a lot of time to interrupt the thread. I need immediately child thread should throw InterruptedException, how I can do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stopping thread Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911118/stopping-thread-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

Srikant.

1. The best way is to have control of the execution of the thread and make it ends along with its flow, instead of interrupting it. To do it, you should implement a flag to check at specific checkpoints of the thread flow.
2. Consider that if you want to check that flag, you must wait for some subprocess into the thread, like SVN operations. For that reason, you must take care of these subprocesses.
3. The thread will be finished after the function `run()` ends. That's the correct way to finish a thread, in an "organic" way. So, you should look for how to finish your thread in that way, instead of forcing it.

```java
public void stop()
{
   if(flag) 
     flag=false;
}

public void run()
{
   while(flag)
   {
      if(flag)
        svn.oper1()
      else
       break; //Exit while

      if(flag)
        svn.oper2()
      else
       break; //Exit while
   }

   notifyTheadFinishEvent(); //Notify to main thread.
   //Thread ends
}
```

Of course, you should be aware of Race Conditions to operate the flag between the Stop and the conditions.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) you can find the reasons that JAVA deprecated suspend and stop operation into a thread.

Comment: In order to check that flag I need to wait till completion of SVN checkout and if the file size is more then it will take more time to complete the process.

Comment: The main idea is that the thread should end its tasks in the best way that it could. In your case, you should wait that the process, which is not in your control, like svn, ends properly to finish the thread, which is under your control.